# Android Listview does not be scrollable at the end

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Iam loading some xml data and parsing it, then display it in listview by custom array adapter.
In the last item the listview does not load all the text and it does not be scrollable to get the text as the following image:

[image: Image describe the problem]

And this is the template xml i use to display the data in the ListView:

[image: image to clearfy the problem]

I don't know what should i drag exactly, but i hope this is clearfy.

Answer (score 0):

based on this topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46093609/8244139

you should write this code in your style so the context appear between appbar and nav bar:

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Comment: I solve it, The problem here i need to wrap the LisView content, in the first image the layout_height of the listView was fixed, when i change it to be wrap the content it became display all the content.